# POST Request using fetch API not returning updated data

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to make a post request with a string. The server is supposed to return the same string, but with an ID added to it to the response.

However, this is the response (Success: ...) that I am getting:

[image]

The server is supposed to return the same string as "sent: ..." with ID added to it, but it's just noting that the POST request was successful.

Here's the code that I am using to accomplish this task (vanilla JS):

```
function saveForm() {
  var street = document.getElementById("street").value;
  var provinceId = document.getElementById("province").value;
  var provinceName = provinces[provinceId]
  var cityId = document.getElementById("city").value;
  var cityName = cities[cityId].name
  var message = document.getElementById("message").value;

  var postData = {
    Notes: message,
    Address: `${provinceName},${cityName},${street}`,
  };

  // sent: {...}
  console.log("sent: ", JSON.stringify(postData));

  fetch("https://wavy-media-proxy.wavyapps.com/investors-notebook/inst1/", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(postData),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
  })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("Success: ", data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    });
}
```

The server has CORS blocked, and I need to change the content-type to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` as compared to the usual `"application/json"`

To solve this issue I tried changing the data format to be an object. I also tried to console.log the data in different formats. I checked the network tab, and have not found anything there in the response.

I am out of options but to ask for help. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The admin of the server told me he gave me the wrong format for the POST request. It has to include 'entry'.

[image]

Comment: Well (a) the screenshot doesn't show us what the response body actually is and (b) Lying about the Content-Type is unlikely to help the server process the Content you are posting.

Comment: If you're sending JSON, it should be `application/json`, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: What format does the server actually expect the parameters to be in? If it expects urlencoded, you shouldn't be sending JSON.

Comment: fetch returns a promise of a Response object. So you need to do something like Fetch().then((response) => response.json().then((data) => data.yourStuff);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `then((response) => response.json())` after fetch() function to get the response in JSON format, so it should look like:

```
fetch("https://wavy-media-proxy.wavyapps.com/investors-notebook/inst1/", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(postData),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("Success: ", data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    });
```

You can read more about `fetch` API in the official doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your backend API does not return what you expect? When replacing it with another API and changing the content type to `application/json` it works:

```js
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({Post:123,Data:456}),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("Success: ", data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    });
```